# Unable to trigger off events when input ID is clicked

Tags: jquery

Currently have the following code, where by when the button is clicked, i want it to trigger off certain events, however, nothing seems to happen. Any help would be benficial:

Appending input button:

```
var row = $("<DIV></DIV>").addClass("row resource").attr("resource", "new");
var label = $("<SPAN></SPAN>").addClass("label imaged").text("New resource");
var spanEl = $("<SPAN>&nbsp</SPAN>").addClass("defaultJobType");
spanEl.append($("<input id ='setDefaultJobType' type='submit' name='Default' value='Set Default'/>"));        
label.append(spanEl);
```

When clicked, it should go into the following code:

```
$("#setDefaultJobType", context).click(function() {
                clickedDefaultJob($(this));
            });
```

Which triggers of the following:

```
function clickedDefaultJob($el) {
            //Remove bold tags from previous job type
            $("div.row.ordertype").each(function(){
                   if(($(this).text()).length>0){
                    $("strong").contents().unwrap();
                   }    
            })
            //assign default bold text to selected job type
            var row = $el.closest(".row");
            var rowNumber = row.attr("key");
            var defaultVal = row.find(".defaultVal INPUT");
            var jobTypeNameEl = $el.closest(".label.imaged");
            jobTypeNameEl.wrapInner("<strong />");
            var value = jobTypeNameEl.text();
            updateSetting("<%=Setting.SET_DEFAULT_JOBTYPE%>", rowNumber, "int");
        }
```

Comment: What's `context` here?

Comment: You likely want to delegate: `$(document).on("click","#setDefaultJobType" function() {`

Comment: Use jQuery .on() method to bind event to elements which may be added into DOM in later stage.

$("#setDefaultJobType").on('click', function() {
                clickedDefaultJob($(this));
 });